# Generate powerset up to a certain length

Tags: c++, string, permutation

I was using bit-shift to generate a powerset of a given numeric string. How can I restrict it to a certain length, say 4, and thus improve the execution time by not finding the subsequences of undesired length.

For ex: if given numeric string is `10292`, then only following subsequences are needed: 1029, 102, 109, 029, 0292, etc (only with digits 4,3,2,1).

Following is my code:

```
scanf("%s", &str); //read numeric string
int n = strlen(str); //find size of string

// loop to find subsequences or powerset
for ( i = 1; i < ( 1 << n ); ++i ) {
    string subseq;
    for ( j = 0; j < n; ++j ) {
        if ( i & ( 1 << j ) ) {
            subseq+=str[j];
        }          
    }

    cout << subseq << endl; //print the subsequence
}
```

Comment: Is this also homework as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774059/generate-subsequences ?

Comment: @RomanSaveljev: No, not homework. Its a codechef question.

Comment: @jahhaj: No. I have to consider all digits of given string. And take only those subsequeces whose size is <=4.

Comment: Yes sorry I misunderstood, I've deleted my comment. You have your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a filter in front of the print statement.

```
if (subseq.length() <= 4) cout<<subseq<<endl;
```

Comment: I thought of it; even I tried. But it won't save the precious time to calculate subsequences of undesired length, which is what I want to do.

Comment: Ah, you want it to be *fast*.  You should add that requirement to the question.

Comment: @StalinSubramaniam: Well in that case I think you need to drop your 'bit-shift' method and switch to a recursive approach. A recursive approach can easily count the number of characters included so far and stop when that reaches four. Plus a recursive method wouldn't be limited by the number of bits in an integer.